# runtime time error in Vs2010 built clr project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, command-line-interface

In my clr project when  I am creating instance of a managed class with gcnew it is showing an error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

the Test.dll is given as reference and also exist in specified path. What would be the reason for it ?

below is the code snippet

```
using namespace Test;<br>
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])<br>
 {
int a = 10;<br>
Run^ aa = gcnew Run();<br>
aa->Execute();<br>
return 0;
}
```